# Lambda Expression Local variable text defined in an enclosing scope JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, scope, minesweeper

I am using JavaFX to create a minesweeper game. I have a lambda expression where (for now) when I press a button from the grid of buttons, it sets the text of the button to be the location in the 2D array. I am getting the error "Local variable text defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final."

I understand that the variables I am using in the lambda expression cant be done because they have to be final outside the expression. but I cant figure out how to get around that.

```
static Stage stage;
Button[][] buttonGrid;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    SetSettings.readSettings();
    GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

    int gridSize = Minesweeper.gridSize;
    buttonGrid = new Button[gridSize][gridSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
            buttonGrid[i][j] = new Button();
            GridPane.setConstraints(buttonGrid[i][j], j, i);

        }
    }
    String text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
            text += i + "" + j;
            buttonGrid[i][j].setOnAction(e -> {
                buttonGrid[i][j].setText(text);
                text = "";

            });
            gridpane.getChildren().add(buttonGrid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    stage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        e.consume();
        ConfirmExit.display("Exit", "Are you sure you want to quit this game?");
    });
    primaryStage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/Logo.jpg"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane, 600, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

It is flagging i, j, and text in the same error.

gridSize is the size of my grid for minesweeper. buttonGrid is the grid of buttons I am placing in the gridPane.

I saw a solution on stackoverflow to set these variables as global, but that did not work.

Comment: There is no "global" in java and even if you convert the variables to fields this would not work. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but even assuming you  copy the results to new variables in the inner loop/create a field, the logic seems weird: The first time a button would be clicked the text of that button would be changed to contain all the combinations of indices, for all clicks that happen after the text would be removed...

Comment: @fabian I have added my full code. Hope this helps you understand what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the definition of `text` inside the loop (so you define a new, effectively final, variable on each iteration of the loop). You can also define a `Button` variable in the same way, to avoid referencing `i` and `j`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
        String text = i + "" + j;
        Button button = buttonGrid[i][j] ;
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            button.setText(text);    
        });
        gridpane.getChildren().add(buttonGrid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: then how do i add the value of i and j if I make a new button?

Comment: @SakshamGoyal I don't understand what you mean by "add the value of `i` and `j`". And this code doesn't create any new buttons.

Comment: added full code to OP. do you understand what im trying to do npw?

Comment: @SakshamGoyal I don’t really understand what you’re trying to do with the string concatenation, or why you’re resetting `text` in the event handler. It’s not clear what you expect to happen there. What text do you want to appear in button (I,j) when it’s pressed?

Comment: You said: *”when I press a button from the grid of buttons, it sets the text to be the location in the 2D array”*, which is what the code I posted does.

Comment: the position of the button in the buttonGrid. so if I press the top left button, the text should say "00"

Comment: What I understand from your code is that its creating a copy of a button in buttonGrid and settings its action. but then you are adding the original button without making buttonGrid[i][j] into that copy

Comment: @SakshamGoyal Huh? How am I “creating a copy of a button”?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211774/discussion-between-saksham-goyal-and-james-d).